# how to use htmlspecialchars in the following code:

Tags: php

Someone told me that I have to use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting to the screen but do I need it here under the $headers' section because I can't get it to work with it:

```
$company = "pianocourse101@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Activate your Premium membership Level 1 monthly account";
$mailTo = htmlspecialchars($email);
$headers = "From: ",htmlspecialchars($company);
$txt = "Thank you for registering with pianocourse101! At pianocourse101, your child can now learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home! \n\nOur lessons are based from the Bastien Piano Basics series because it is both fun and educational for your child. \n\nHowever, you must activate your Premium membership Level 1 monthly account by clicking on the link below: \n\n http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=",htmlspecialchars($mailTo),"&activatetoken=",htmlspecialchars($token);

mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

I have a comma parse error..

Comment: Whats the error message?

Answer (score 0):

`$headers = "From: ".htmlspecialchars($company);`

You should replace the comma with a point.
Commas are for enumerating parameters, points to concat strings.

Comment: Just for that line? Because the , seems to work for the rest of the code

Comment: Oh, you should replace them in the $txt as well

Comment: $company = "pianocourse101@hotmail.com";
                                 $subject = "Activate your Premium membership Level 1 monthly account";
                                 $mailTo = htmlspecialchars($email);
                                 $headers = "From: ".htmlspecialchars($company);

Comment: How would I go about in adding attachment? I read that phpmailer is a better choice but I would like to try it with mail()

Comment: I got another problem now and not sure what it is because I didn't change anything in the logout form

Comment: but my logout button is not showing anymore and the header2.php file is not included

Comment: I get a blank page when I typed my logout.php file

Comment: echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=create_music_topic.php?cat=',htmlspecialchars($cat),'&topic_id=',htmlspecialchars($topic_id),'&id=',htmlspecialchars($id),'>';

Comment: I am still a bit confused when to use a dot and comma

Comment: Should I use a dot here or comma for the below code?

Comment: echo'
           <tr>
          <th> Category</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['category']),'</td>
          </tr>       
          <tr>
          <th>Sub Category</th><td><a href="display_music_forum_topics.php?cat=',htmlspecialchars($row['id']),'&admin=',htmlspecialchars($row['admin']),'&topic_id=',htmlspecialchars($row2['id']),'">',htmlspecialchars($row2['sub_category']),'</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Creator</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['user_uid']),'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Date Created</th>